# Autoload not pulling in use_helper() after upgrading Symfony 1.4 project to PHP 8.2 via FriendsOfSymfony

Tags: symfony1, undefined-function

I'm attempting to upgrade a large legacy Symfony 1.4 project to run under PHP 8.2 (currently running under PHP 5.6) using the FriendsOfSymfony project. Upgrade to Symfony 5.4 will come later when we have more budget, the current priority is to get off PHP 5.6.

I used `composer require friendsofsymfony1/symfony1 "1.5.*"` to install the new symfony libraries, and updated the top of my config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php file to contain `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../vendor/autoload.php';`

I am getting a `Call to undefined function use_helper()` in my app.

I can see use_helper() defined at `vendor/friendsofsymfony1/symfony1/lib/helper/HelperHelper.php` so I'm not sure why autoload isn't pulling it in.